# Slow keyboard response in some Distros

Tags: keyboard

I will be quick and clear.

My keyboard is very slow in Gentoo, Debian, Ubuntu, Arch, PCLinuxOS and LinuxMint.
It works fine in Mandriva, Fedora and Sabayon (Gentoo Based)

It is slow even in Gentoo installation; without the Xs, with KDE; Gnome, Fluxbox...

I just want to use Arch Linux, but I can't even install it !
Help please.

EDIT: Can this be the problem ? http://lwn.net/Articles/404712/

Comment: So is your problem "my keyboard is slow" or "I can't install Arch Linux"?  Is it so slow that you can't pass through Arch Linux installation?

Comment: It's "My keyboard is slow", but I said it's even slow in Arch Linux install.

Comment: What do you mean by “keyboard is slow”? Do you mean that it takes a long time between pressing a key and having a visible effect? How slow is slow (seconds, minutes, …)? What kind of keyboard: USB, PS/2, …? Do you have a spare keyboard that you could try (to see how dependent the problem is on a particular hardware)?

Comment: The Keyboard (KB from now) is the embedded laptop one. If I write quick... "shutdown" for example; it only shows; "hon" or just random letters.

Comment: @dysoco Ok, so the system is dropping key presses. This bug could be the issue; if it is, you'll need to get a distribution where the kernel version is 2.6.34.7 or above (or perhaps a distribution that's too old to have the bug).

Comment: Tried Ubuntu 11.04 with kernel 2.6.38 and the KB is slow.